# TextInputEditText programmatically set hint not goes up on focus

Tags: hint, android-textinputedittext

I am changing hint based on phone number and id, if user is entering number then I am programmatically setting hint to *Enter 10 digits* and when user enter id, the hint is *Enter 5 digits*
Now the problem is, when I focus on **TextInputEditText**, the hint doesn't goes up.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textinput_web_ref"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorA">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tv_web_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorA"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTransparent"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorA" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

code

```
if (title.getText().toString().contentEquals("ID")) {
    inputEditText.setHint("Enter 5 digits");
} else {
    inputEditText.setHint("Enter 10 digits");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set hint on TextInputLayout.
For example:

```
if (title.getText().toString().contentEquals("ID")) {
    textInputLayout.setHint("Enter 5 digits");
} else {
    textInputLayout.setHint("Enter 10 digits"); 
}
```

TextInputLayout is generally a layout which wraps a TextInputEditText, EditText, or descendant to show a floating label when the hint is hidden while the user inputs text.
So, your hint becomes the floating label when the user is writing anything in textInputEditText.